# extract and group elements together with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get this output:

> *******Movie Titles:******** 
>  *World War Z*
>
>   ********Casts:********* 
> Brad Pitt
> Mireille Enos
> James Badge Dale
>
> *******Movie Titles:******** 
>  *Monsters University*
> ********Casts:********* 
> Johnny
>   Depp
> Watsons Junior

```
<h2 itemprop="name">World War Z</h2>
<div class=info>‎1hr 56min‎‎ - Rated PG13‎‎ - Action/Drama/Horror‎‎ - English‎<br>
 - Cast: 
<span itemprop="actors">Brad Pitt</span>, 
<span itemprop="actors">Mireille Enos</span>, 
<span itemprop="actors">James Badge Dale</span>
</div>

<h2 itemprop="name">Monsters University</h2>
<div class=info>‎2hr 30min‎‎ - Rated PG13‎‎ - Comedy‎‎ - English‎<br>
 - Cast: 
<span itemprop="actors">Johnny Depp</span>, 
<span itemprop="actors">Watsons Junior</span>
</div>
```

I've tried doing this:

```
    Elements movieTitle = doc.select("h2");
    for (Element src : movieTitle) {
        for (int i = 0; i < movieTitle.size(); ++i) {
            title += movieTitle.get(i).text() + "\n";
        }
        break;
    }

    Elements casts = doc.select("span[itemprop=actors]");
    for (Element sr : casts) {
        for (int i = 0; i < casts.size(); ++i) {
            cast += casts.get(i).text() + "\n";
        }
        break;
    }
System.out.println("*************Movie Titles:************* \n" + title);
System.out.println("*************Casts:************* \n" + cast);
```

But the output is:

> *******Movie Titles:********
>
>    *World War Z 
>
>   Monsters University*
>
>
>   ********Casts:********* 
> Brad Pitt
> Mireille Enos
> James Badge Dale
> Johnny Depp
> Watsons Junior

How do I group the casts according to the movies?

Comment: Maybe better to try and parse sequentially, then it would be easier to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the results in desired format.

```
 Elements items = doc.select("h2");
    for (Element movieElement : items) {

        //Here you get movie name from movieElement
        Elements castElemets =  movieElement.nextElementSibling().select("span[itemprop=actors]");
        //loop through the castElemnts for corresponding Movie
    }
```